# Excel VBA .find command not working for me

Tags: excel, find, vba

I have an Excel 2013 sheet that has lots of tabs. Each tab holds license keys for a different piece of software that  our company has.  The License is then tied to the Computer it is installed on.  I am writing a macro that lists all the tabs that a a search string is found on.  If i leave the inputbox empty, it will list all the tabs.  But if i type in something to search for it does nothing but show the end of macro message.

```
Sub TempMacro()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    SearchListRow = 3
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FindSting As String

    FindString = InputBox("Enter a Search value")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        'Set Search Function
        Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=FindString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'Record tab name where string was found
            Sheets("LISTS").Range("O" & SearchListRow) = ws.Name
            'incriment row
            SearchListRow = SearchListRow + 1
        Else
            'MsgBox ("Nothing found in " & wb.Name)
        End If
    Next ws
    MsgBox ("End Macro")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your cells object is not fully qualified. What you are doing is searching the activesheet only. You need to add `Ws` before `Cells` so that it searches in those sheets

Try this

```
Set rng = Ws.Cells.Find(What:=FindString......
```

also `LookAt:=xlWhole` does an exact match. For partial matches, you will have to use `xlPart`

Comment: That worked PERFECT!  I knew it had to be something small i was missing.  Thank you very much for your quick response and help.